# Is it possible to create a linearly random selection of an array using Array.prototype.reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, random

Using the signature for [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (or `Array.prototype.reduceRight`), is it possible to select an item from the array with an equal probability for all indices? Here's my attempt:

```js
document.write(`
${[...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'].reduce(function(last, next, index, array) {
  if (Math.random() > index / array.length) {
    return next;
  }

  return last;
})}
`);
```

After doing a few test runs of this, the distribution appears to be skewed towards the lower indices (which is to say that the upper indices are selected more often).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Example:_sample_size_1) for this: Always select the first element, then as you iterate through the array, replace the item you currently have selected with the k<sup>th</sup> (1-based indexing) item, with `1/k` probability. This will give you a uniform probability:

```
document.write(`
${[...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'].reduce(function(last, next, index, array) {
  if ( Math.random()*(index + 1) <= 1 ) {
    return next;
  }

  return last;
})}
`);
```

Here is a test to demonstrate that it does return each letter with a uniform probability:

```js
var results = {};
for ( var i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
    var choice = [...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'].reduce(function(last, next, index, array) {
        if ( Math.random()*(index + 1) <= 1 ) {
            return next;
        }

        return last;
    } );
    results[ choice ] = (results[ choice ] || 0) + 1;
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify( results, '\t' ) + '</pre>';
```